# Get last two characters of each words in a comma separated string

Tags: php, string

I am trying to find a solution for my for my following case in php:

```
$string = "Korata Kb, Montara Mt, Guztre Gr, Kisllar Kl";
```

I would like to have the last two characters of each part of comma separated..

$result = Kb, Mt, Gr, Kl;

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `explode -> map -> substr -> join` ?

Comment: Hi, is that possible to say to get the last record from back until the first white space? The result should be the same for the above string. But When the string would have: $string = "Korata Kob, Montara Mt" then the result would be: $result = Kob, Mt

Comment: Hi, I just solved my issue with the following code:

implode(', ', array_map(fn($s) => substr($s, strrpos($s, ' ') + 1), explode(',', $string)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode at the comma and extract the last two characters.

```
$string = "Korata Kb, Montara Mt, Guztre Gr, Kisllar Kl";
$result = implode(', ', array_map(fn($s) => substr($s, -2, 2), explode(',', $string)));
echo $result;
```

```
Kb, Mt, Gr, Kl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first transform the string into an array. Walk through all values and get the 2 last characters and add them to an array and concat them with a comma again.

```
<?php

$string = "Korata Kb, Montara Mt, Guztre Gr, Kisllar Kl";
$names = explode(",", $string);
$snippets = array();

foreach ($names as $name) {
   $snippets[] = substr($name, -2);
}

$snippetString = implode(",",$snippets);
echo $snippetString;
```

Have a look at [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php), [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)